# NSCoding in Swift

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I have a great problem when decoding my class.
The code is the following:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.statistics = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("playerStatistics") as [Team:[Competition:Statistics]]
}
```

Team, Competition and Statistics are classes but when encoding I always get an error: "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException" `"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Statistics.Team copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16665ed0'"`. What *could* be possible mistakes? Can the error occur due to one of the classes in the Dictionary? The only value of the dictionary is set when initializing the object:

```
self.statistics[Team(name: "<default>"] = [Competition:Statistics]()
```

*Any* help would be great!

Comment: Do the Team, Competition and Statistics classes have the init(Coder) defined for them? AFAIK, NSCoder can deal only with system defined types on its own and hence it is necessary to define the decoder/coder for all of the dependent classes.

Comment: Yes, all of them implement the NSCoding protocol as well as the NSObject class, of course. Maybe I should mention that the error occurs only since I do the line from above when initializing the object. But anyway, it could have other reasons, too.

Comment: I copied the error in my question @insane-36

Comment: `self.statistics[Team(name: "<default>"] = [Competition:Statistics]()` That is not valid Swift so it cannot be what you are really saying.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I forgot to close the brackets. Actually above that's not the real code because I have a more complex team that is initialized before but it would have been to complicated to mention that.

Comment: For the record, this question doesn't deserve the down-votes it has received. Yes, earlier iterations omitted salient details, but now that this is clarified, this question actually identifies a subtle issue entailed in `NSCoding` compliance in Swift which is not documented elsewhere. Good question, Oliver!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is telling you that `Team` must conform to `NSCopying`. I suspect that the unarchiving/decoding process is using `NSDictionary` internally, and `NSDictionary` requires that the key conforms to `NSCopying`. If the `Team` class conforms to `NSCopying` (i.e. implement the `copyWithZone` method), this error goes away.

By the way, because `Team` is a dictionary key, I assume you've also made it conform to `Hashable` (and `Equatable`), too. This is a requirement of Swift dictionary keys.

Comment: Thank you very much for this information I don't get the error anymore _but_ I don't know what to write into `copyWithZone()`- I get an error using: `return self.copy() as Team`

Comment: By the way the error I'm getting is during runtime: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

Comment: You can `return Team(name: name)`

Comment: Thank you so much for this **very** helpful information!